# SIGHUP from a terminal

Tags: c, linux, process, ssh, signals

Experts,
I have a client that connects over ssh to a server (it gets a tty allocated). I have a process  A that is running on the server. Now, whenever the client disconnects, I need A to know about the tty that vanishes.

I was thinking since SSHD knows the session dying (after timeout or a simple exit), it can generate a signal to process A.

Is there any other way that A can get information about the tty that vanishes like listening on SIGHUP for the tty? I am writing the code in C on Linux.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX.1 provides a facility, [utmpx](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/utmpx.h.html), which lists the currently logged in users, their terminals, and other information. In Linux, that is the same as utmp; see [`man 5 utmp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html) for further information.

OpenSSH does maintain utmp records.

Here is a simple example, that lists all users currently logged in from remote machines, the terminal they are using, and the initial process group the user owns:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmpx.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct utmpx *entry;

    setutxent();
    while ((entry = getutxent()))
        if (entry->ut_type == USER_PROCESS && entry->ut_host[0] != '\0')
            printf("%s is logged in on /dev/%s from %s and owns process group %d\n", 
                   entry->ut_user, entry->ut_line, entry->ut_host,
                   (int)getpgid(entry->ut_pid));

    return 0;
}
```

In your case, I would expect process A to maintain a list of remotely connected users, and periodically do a similar loop as above to update the status of known entries and to add new entries; and remove entries that are no longer seen.

New entries then match a "login" event, entries that are no longer seen a "logout" event (and deleted after the loop), and all other events are "still logged in" users.

The loop above is quite lightweight in terms of CPU time used and I/O used. The utmp records (`/var/run/utmp` in most Linux machines) are in binary form, and if frequently accessed, usually in page cache. Entries are relatively small, and even on servers with a lot of users the file read is well under a megabyte in size. Still, I wouldn't do it in a tight loop.

Personally, I would use [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) to wait for `CLOSE_WRITE` events on the `UTMPX_FILE` file (`/var/run/utmp` on most Linux machines), and reread the records after each event. That way the service would block on the `read()` on the inotify file descriptor most of the time (not wasting any CPU time), and pretty much immediately react to any login/logout events.

Comment: Wow! I didnt know about utmp and inotify. This might be helpful too. Let me try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You face two problems, both difficult.  The succinct answer is "you can't"; the longer answer is "you can't without making significant modifications".

1. A signal relays very little information other than the fact that it occurred.  If you use [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) and `SA_SIGINFO`, you can find the process ID of the process that sent the signal, but under your scheme, that would be `sshd`, which isn't dreadfully helpful.  Thus, it will be hard (nigh on impossible) to get the information about which terminal via the signal.  Obviously, other schemes can be defined, but you'd have to write the information to a file, or something similar.
2. You'd have to modify `sshd` to record the information about which terminal it allocates (or is allocated) to its child processes, and then arrange for it to send that information to your Process A when a child terminates.  That would be tricky, at best.

These two factors alone make it rather difficult.  If you still want to do it, then the way I'd try is by getting `sshd` to run a special process of your devising, which in turn forks and the child runs the the process that `sshd` would otherwise run.  The parent (a) records which terminal the child is connected to, and (b) waits for the child to terminate.  When it does, it writes the terminal information to somewhere that Process A will find it, and exits.  You still have to revise `sshd`, and you have to devise a mechanism whereby the parent process knows what to run as the child process (but that's probably not very hard; you leave the argument list unchanged, but simply have `sshd` exec your monitor process instead of whatever is specified as `argv[0]`…the parent uses `argv[0]` as the file argument to `execvp()`.

This scheme minimizes the changes to `sshd` (but does still require a non-standard version).  And you have to write the parent code carefully, and it has to cooperate with Process A.  All decidedly non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks. But, the real issue is I cant have a special process. when I login through ssh, I am launching a special shell which is the one handling requests from ssh client. This shell uses sockets to communicate with A to get some info. So each ssh client will have its own shell launched and user chooses whether to get the stdout of A redirected or not. If the user chooses to get the stdout through a client shell, I need to handle the client termination. ie process A shouldnt redirect stdout to the client shell anymore. This is where I am having issues hence the above question.

Comment: Then your special shell that communicates with A will have to arrange that A knows when it terminates.  One possibility is to have the shell create and open a FIFO for writing, while Process A opens the FIFO for reading.  Process A can arrange to be told when the other end of the FIFO is closed, and then delete the FIFO.

Comment: Thats sounds like a neat idea. Let me try. But if the client terminates abruptly (network issue for example), will this shell be removed? (remember when user logs in with certain loginid, in passwd file I am launching this shell). If shell is killed, unless the FIFO is closed explicitly that FIFO still remains and A wont get any notification correct?

Comment: Pass...I don't know whether the shell will be removed, but I'd expect it would go in fairly short order.  The FIFO will be closed when the shell dies; all open file descriptors are closed when the process dies.  That's the advantage of this mechanism; if the process on the writing end dies for any reason, the read end (Process A) gets EOF the next time it tries to read from the FIFO. Note that the FIFO names need to be unique.

Comment: Yep you are correct. I just did RTFM :) The only problem now is getting the tty allocated for the ssh client that terminated.

Comment: If your special shell communicates with Process A, it can write the name of its tty on the FIFO in a first message to Process A. And it can determine its tty name via `ttyname()`.